# Is there a way to include the input in the bash file so that I will not type the input required in the command line every time I run the bash script

Tags: bash

I am utilizing bash scripts to perform auto deployment on live site with Ubuntu server.

One of the line has something like:

```
scp build.zip user_name@ip_address:/path/to/releases/$release
```

Once the Ubuntu execute this command, it will ask me for password input in the command line like:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Is there a way to include the input in the bash file so that I will not type the password in the command line every time I run the bash script?

Comment: See ssh-agent etc. This varies by OS, and probably belongs on a different stack.

Comment: Use `sshpass`. See: `man sshpass`

Answer (score 0):

You could use another file in which you write the needed input lines.

```
./your_script.sh < your_input_file.txt
```

But that really don't seem like the best idea, I'd rather try to prevent the need for input in each of the sub-commands.

Answer (score -1):

You can permanently remove the passphrase on your `id_rsa` key by running this command and setting a new blank passphrase:

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

---

For a generic solution, you can use an `expect` script to programmatically drive and interact with a terminal session.

Comment: Yeah possible, but it's not the only line that ask for command line input. for example database password also

Comment: Every program will have a different way to deal with this.  I suggest post another question; also probably best to ask on https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/.  I added an alternative...